# Plotting images and labels as a bar chart using matplotlib and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

So I have to plot the distribution of images in a dataset as a bar chart. I've looked at several ways of doing this but to no avail.

I have two numpy arrays:

X_train - shape (20000, 32, 32, 3)
y_train - shape(20000)

labels - Dictionary of label indexes to label strings. Size 50

So X_train contains the images and y_train contains the corresponding label indexes

I need to plot a bar chart of X_train against the 50 labels. Showing the distribution of the number of images for each label.

Should I first group the images in the X_train array by the corresponding index in y_train ? How does this fit into the matplotlib.bar API call ?

Or should I be using numpy histogram API.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to just use the [histogram](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) with some additional arguments. You could use something like,

```
In [55]: y
Out[55]: array([0, 0, 1, 2, 1])

In [54]: plt.hist(y, align='mid', range=(np.min(y), np.max(y)+1), bins=50)
In [55]: plt.xlabel("labels")
In [56]: plt.ylabel("image counts")
In [57]: plt.show()
```

[image]

Here, the plot says label 0 & 1 appears 2 times and 2 appear once.
Get the labels from `y_train` and plot it against its counts. Feel free to change the number of bins according to the labels that you have.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this post was posted 3 years ago and maybe you don't need the answer anymore, but this might help others who are looking for the answer. This is on CIFAR10 dataset and the training dataset is split into training and validation:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.1, random_state=1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_val = x_val.astype('float32')


classes = ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']

list_classes_train = []
list_classes_val = []

for i in range(len(np.unique(y_train))):

    idx_train = np.where(y_train == i)
    idx_train = idx_train[0]
    x_train, y_train = x_train[idx_train], y_train[idx_train]

    idx_val = np.where(y_val == i)
    idx_val = idx_val[0]
    x_val, y_val = x_val[idx_val], y_val[idx_val]

    #print("The training samples of class {} -> {} is {}" .format(i, classes[i], x_train.shape))
    #print("The validation samples of class {} -> {} is {}" .format(i, classes[i], x_val.shape))

    list_classes_train.append(x_train.shape[0])
    list_classes_val.append(x_val.shape[0])

    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
    x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.1, random_state=1)
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
    x_val = x_val.astype('float32')

x = np.arange(len(classes))
width = 0.35

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, list_classes_train, width, label='train')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, list_classes_val, width, label='val')

ax.set_ylabel('data points')
ax.set_title('Training and Validation set')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(classes, rotation = 90)
ax.legend()


def autolabel(rects):
    """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')


autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Result is:

[image: bar plot of training and Validation set]

For plotting just training set

```
y_pos = range(len(classes))
plt.bar(y_pos, list_classes_train)

# Rotation of the bars names

bars = ax.bar(y_pos, list_classes_train)
# plt.xticks(y_pos, classes, rotation=90)

for rect in bars:
    height = rect.get_height()
    plt.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2.0, height, '%d' % int(height), ha = 'center', va = 'bottom')

plt.show()
```

Result is

[image: bar plot of training set]